# Report builder 3.0 Using Reportitems!TexboxXX.Value sometimes creates multiple boxes. Why?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have 6 Datasets each one is the same query but has a different WHERE clause based on employee type. They generate 6 tables. At the top of the report there is a summary table which uses reportitems!textboxXX.value to grab the totals for 2 particular fields from all the tables. I'm also using a StartDate and EndDate parameter. Each reportitems! expression in the table comes from a different dataset in the report if that is relevant.

When I run the report using dates from yesterday back to the 9th of May I get the desired output.

[image: pic 1]

But when I go to the 8th I get multiple rows all the same.

[image: pic2]

and as I go even further back I get even more rows of the same information. To my knowledge nothing interesting or different happened on the 8th of May and the tables further down the report look exactly the same. Any idea what might be causing this? The design view looks like this if that helps. There's no grouping or filters on the table.

[image: design]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not certain about the mechanics behind this but I found a 'solution' so I figured I'd post it. I just made a new dataset for my summary tables where the query was simply SELECT 1. Now I get a single row every time.